# Is it possible to serialize objects made from different class in the same xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, .net-3.5

For example, I got the class `Header`, and the class `Dog`. 
I would like a file that looks like this:

[image]

So far, I have seen no examples to perform this. I must use the
`serializer.Serialize` because I got a collection of thousands of
objects. Doing otherwise would take too long.

If it is impossible, I will make two different files, one with the
header and the other with the collection of objects, but it is not an
interesting solution.

**Edit:**
I can't use a wrapper since I don't have my complete dog list at the 
beginning. I receive one at the time until I stop the application

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create another class the can represent this. For example.

```
public class Kennel
{
    public Header Header { get; set; }
    public List<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
}
```

This can then be serialized/deserialized easily.

In answer to your question. If you need the XML to be identical to yours, you will need to create a custom wrapper that will read and write the XML into that specific format.

Comment: I see, and this is a good idea. But the problem is that I need to add an element each time I receive one. I don't write my document in one shot, but one objectat the time. First I need to add my header, and each second a new object (dog in this exemple). At the end, I close my document. I wont have the complete object at the beginning, what makes it impossible.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You have the class that has a Header class and a List of Dogs. You can add to this List<Dog> whenever you want and then serialize it to an xml file as and when. If you need multiple Kennels, then create another class that has List<Kennel> and serialize this.

Comment: I won't serialize it at the end, I want to do it as soon as I receive a dog. If the application fail, I won't lose all the data.

Comment: As said, you can serialize/save whenever you want.

Comment: I tried to look if there was some sort of misunderstanding, but what I want to do is not to feed a list because my data is huge. I don't want to pollute memory. Once the object is written in the xml file, it is left behind. I want to write a dog in my file each time I get one, not once my list is complete. Just to give you an idea, My xml file can be more than one gig heavy. I won't keep the whole thing in a list. I would write my xml the hard way rather than doing this. THanks for the help, but I believe that I will have to continue searching.

Answer (score 0):

I would looking at making a custom wrapper class (call it: `DogWrapper` or something) that contained a Header object and a list (or array, or whatever) of type `Dog`.  Then use custom serialization to define how to write out that object.

Then you just marshal your header and dogs into a DogWrapper, and serialize the DogWrapper.